# How to count values with a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the table below I need to get which sport has won the highest medals. The column of medals include Gold, Silver and Bronze.
[image: IMAGE 1]

I made a groupby and count the medals put it divide the amount of medals by gold, silver and bronze, and I just need the total of them in a specific sport.
[image: IMAGE 2]

Comment: refer to the guidelines in posting a reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: would you try this? `df.groupby(['Sport', 'Medal']).agg('count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in a csv file

```
import pandas as pd

# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('athlete_events.csv')

# groupby Sport and Medal and get the counts
dfg = df.groupby(['Sport', 'Medal']).Medal.count().reset_index(name='counts')

# pivot the dfg
dfp = dfg.pivot(index='Sport', columns='Medal', values='counts')

# add a total column, which will allow dfp to be sorted
dfp['total'] = dfp.sum(axis=1)

# sort dfp
dfp = dfp.sort_values('total', ascending=False)
```